# Почему уходит так много памяти?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Использую `caffe` нейронку (в `c++` проге) для обработки изображений (точнее поиска на них чего-либо). При этом использую `caffe+cuda` так что все расчеты производятся на видеокарте и достаточно быстро. Но меня удивляют размеры выделяемой памяти. К примеру когда я только загружаю нейронку на видеокарту (layer файл где-то около 100Мб) под нее аллоцируется около 1100Мб, а после запуска (`forward`) потребление памяти возрастает еще на 900Мб (все замеры производил с помощью `nvidia-smi`). К тому же после того, как нейронка отработала память (1100 + 900) остается занятой пока не будет вызван деструктор нейронки. Такое потребление памяти вообще нормально?

PS сами изображения, скармливаемые нейронке, занимают не более 100Кб каждое

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название, пожалуйста

Comment: @Kromster с удовольствием, но не знаю как в нескольких словах описать ситуацию

Comment: `сами изображения, скармливаемые нейронке, занимают не более 100Кб каждое` они наверняка сжатые, т.е. там не чистые матрицы с числами-пикселями, а какие-нибудь png/jpg/tiff/и т.п. у меня текущий проект использует opencv и считывая кадры с вебкамеры отдает матрицы по 1мб каждая, но если их кодировать в jpg, то размер уменьшается в 20 раз (~50кб)

Comment: @gil9red они не сжатые - это именно "чистые матрицы". Вообще никогда не слышал о таком, что нейронки работали бы со сжатыми изображениями - ведь в сужности, это могут быть любые данные, а не только изображения